# how to use mouse click event

Tags: java, swing, jlist, mouselistener, mouseclick-event

Hi i have a class where i am using mouseclick event i want to call another class when i click  from my mouse

```
     MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    JList theList = (JList) mouseEvent.getSource();
    if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2) {
      int index = theList.locationToIndex(mouseEvent.getPoint());
      if (index >= 0) {
        Object o = theList.getModel().getElementAt(index);
      //  System.out.println("Double-clicked on: " + o.toString());
         String a=o.toString();


                 LiistSelection.setListIndex(a);
                System.out.println(LiistSelection.getListIndex());
                new MyGui4();
      }
    }
  }
};
```

i want to call this class when user click on list then new window should open

here is my class mygui4.java

```
public class MyGui4 extends JFrame
{
JLabel jLabel1;


Container pane;

 private static ResultSet resultSet = null;
 public void Gui(  )
  {
      {
getContentPane().setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255,153,51));
} 
 this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
Container c = getContentPane();

      setUndecorated(true);
      Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
      setBounds(0,0,screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\a0.png");
       Border border = LineBorder.createGrayLineBorder();
       jLabel1 = new JLabel(image);
       jLabel1.setBorder(border);
      jLabel1.setBackground(Color.red);
     c.add(jLabel1);
     setLayout(null);
  }

  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
      final MyGui4 frame = new MyGui4();

     frame.Gui();

      frame.setVisible(true);

  }
}
```

Comment: And the question is _______????

Comment: Be a bit more specific and also format your code properly :)

Comment: question is that when i click on list then it should return index value and my another class should call which is a jframe window

Comment: i am able to get index value but don know how can i call my another class

Comment: can  any one tell me how can i do this

Comment: I fail to see what the problem is. Calling a method of another class and passing a value as a parameter is Java 101...

Comment: my problem is calling a method of another class

Comment: have you tried creating an instance of that class (where in the method you to use lies) to this class?

Comment: Please edit your question (more detailed) so that it will be more likely answered.

Comment: yes i created a instance of my another class class

Comment: ok i am editing my question

Comment: @@@Ralf17...i updated my one more class which i want to call on mouse click event

Answer (score 0):

You want to Create a object of another Class and call a function  using a object.

```
  class second 
      { 
       //.....
       public void function()
          {
       //........
          }
       public void function(int index)
         {
       //..........
         }
     }
    second s=new second();
    s.function()//calling function 
    int i=10;
    s.function(i)//calling function with parameter
```

Try This Example :

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    class m  extends JFrame 
     {
      String s="The Value of List is  10";
      m()
        {
        setVisible(true);
        pack();
        setLayout(null);
        JButton b=new JButton("Click to Open another form");
        b.setBounds(10,10,200,40);
        add(b);
        b.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
            {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
              {
                  new s(s);//calling another class contructor
              }
              });
           }
          public static void main (String[] args) 
          {
           new m();
          } 
       }

   class s extends JFrame
   {
     s(String s)
     { 
      setVisible(true);
      setSize(100,100);
      setTitle(s);
      }
   }
```

[image]
Click The button Another Class and Open The Window 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are tying to invoke the class MyGui4 from the command line when you start the JVM or from another application when you click on the JList, If so then the code needs to be the same in both places.

When invoked from the command line the main() method is invoked which in turn invokes 3 lines of code:

```
final MyGui4 frame = new MyGui4();
frame.Gui();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

When you invoke the code when clicking on the JList you invoke 1 line of code:

```
new MyGui4();
```

Can you tell me what the difference is?

Of course I still don't understand the point of this code because none of the methods in your MyGui4 class accept a parameter. So it doesn't matter which item in the JList you click on you will still display the same GUI with the same information. You need to pass the selected object from your JList to your GUI.